# osquery file events giving events for un-monitored directory on Mac os

Tags: macos, osquery

Trying to capture file events on mac os

OS: Monterey

osquery table used: es_process_file_events

Flag used: --disable_endpointsecurity_fim=false

I am monitoring two directories /tmp and /usr
but am not getting any file event from this folder surprisingly I am getting events from /Libraray/Application\ Support which even I am not monitoring.
Has anyone faced similar issue?
please help?